VBA / Pivot Table Conundrum
I have an Excel macro that contains a pivot table.  The macro has to read a worksheet and eliminate any line with a code that is not in the following list (1,5, 12, 7, 20).  This part works good.
After the data is finalized, I'm expecting the pivot table to be recreated.  When I look at the filter drop down, all of the codes are there but none of them are checked.  As a result, the pivot table does not contain any data and the macro cannot complete the rest of the code since the pivot able is blank.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Earning Reference Code"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields( _
     "Earning Reference Code")
     .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
     .PivotItems("208").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("213").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("184").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("279").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("195").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("161").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("236").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("190").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("220").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("225").Visible = True
End With

I get an error message when it tries to set the 1st value to True.  (I've also used a variable for the filter name.)  The message says "Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class".
How do I check all of the filter options each time this macro is run?  It has to be dynamic because the final data may not have the same codes each time the macro is run.
Thanks for your help in advance.  I appreciate your time and consideration with my issue........

Is the underlying data strings or integers?

How is "208" connected to the expected list (1,5, 12, 7, 20)?

@taller......"208" is one of the codes that the pivot table is filtered on

eliminate any line with a code that is not in the following list (1,5, 12, 7, 20) - I just don't get the point how is the filtered code connected to the list.

@taller...........I did not show all of the codes in the list.  "208' is one of the codes in the list.  When the pivot table is created, "208" is an option.  Currently 1, 5 , 12, 7, and 20 do not appear in the data source so they aren't options to select.
When the macro is done, the pivot table does not display any data.  I have to manually go to the filters and select the codes I need.  In this case, I would select all of the codes that appear in the drop down.  My goal is to progammatically check all of the filters so all of the data appears in the pivot table.  thanks for your help....

@taller...........I've added a screenshot to the original message.  Sorry it's a little blurry.  You can see there is no data in the pivot table because none of the codes are "checked".  I'm trying to programatically check those codes each time the macro is run.  Those codes can differ from time to time.  Thanks again for your help.......']

Haven't seen the screenshot. CurrentPage = "(All)" shows all items.

@Shaves Does that Item definitely exist in the list?  If there is no matching record, and you don't have "Show items with no data" turned on for that PivotField, then the Item may have automatically been deleted — so VBA/Excel can no longer get that PivotItem from the PivotField because it no longer exists!

Rather than calling for a PivotItem that may-or-may-not exist, you could try looping through the PivotItems that do exist, and check whether or not you want to keep them:
Dim pt As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem, ItemsToKeep As Variant
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
ItemsToKeep = Array("208", "213", "184", "279", "195", "161", "236", "190", "220", "225")

pt.ManualUpdate = True 'This will only recalculate the PivotTable when we tell it to, rather than after every Item change

For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Earning Reference Code").PivotItems
    If IsError(Application.Match(pi.Name, ItemsToKeep, 0)) Then 'Is the PivotItem Name missing from our list?
        pi.Visible = False
    Else
        pi.Visible = True
    End If
Next pi

pt.Update 'Run that manual update now that we have updated all our Items
pt.ManualUpdate = False

Set pt = Nothing


@chronocidal......Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give that a try
